# Is it possible to set Focus or set OnClick for an Android TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

**Problem:** I've been trying to set either the `setOnClickListener` or `setOnFocusChangeListener` on a TableLayout but I'm not getting any response and there are no debug errors or issues I can identify.

**What I'm trying to do:** When someone clicks on the `tablelayout` to add authors, the `EditText` for a single author populates with a standard message (maybe disable it) if the tablelayout has more than one child using `getChildCount()`.

**What I have tried:** As I mentioned, I've tried setting the `setOnClickListener` and `setOnFocusChangeListener` events but nothing seems to happen. I tried setting `Toast` messages to see if it is being activated but I'm not getting anything. I'm not sure what I may be doing wrong. I've set OnClick and Focus for many objects, but this is the first tablelayout and I'm having trouble.

```
tableLayoutAuthors.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            Toast.makeText(AddNote.this,tableLayoutAuthors.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            if(tableLayoutAuthors.getChildCount()>1)
                author.setText(R.string.add_author_phrase);
            else if(tableLayoutAuthors.getChildCount()==1)
                populateSourceDetails(DBQueryTools.getSourcesByTitle(sourceTitle.getText().toString()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you share your layout xml ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a my solution...

Once I selected `addOnLayoutChangeListener` the table would responded as I was hoping. This may not be my final design response but it worked with the following:

```
View tblLayAut = tableLayoutAuthors;
tblLayAut.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        if(tableLayoutAuthors.getChildCount()>1)
            author.setText(R.string.add_author_phrase);
        else if(tableLayoutAuthors.getChildCount()==1)
            populateSourceDetails(DBQueryTools.getSourcesByTitle(sourceTitle.getText().toString()));
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add these XML properties to your TableLayout
as they are set to false by default

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
```